# What worldwide raster basemaps does MapBox provide, and how much do they cost to use?

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, mapbox, basemap

There are a number of MapBox basemaps that show up on various websites (MapBox Streets, MapBox Outdoors), but weirdly, I can't find a list of them anywhere. I have in the past seen a big list of basemaps, including a few of Afghanistan, but they weren't necessarily all worldwide, and I can't find that list now.

There is this short list of half a dozen pretty esoteric maps: https://www.mapbox.com/design/

And various old blog posts that announce new basemaps don't point anywhere anymore: [MapBox Streets](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/announcing-mapbox-streets/), [MapBox Light](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-light-global-base-map-alternative/)

Logging into MapBox I can see this set of basemaps, but is that comprehensive?

[image]

And secondly, how would you go about using a standard MapBox basemap in an application? What's the pricing? Where do you pay?

Do they just not do this anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these are the available basemaps as of v4
https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/#mapids